# Типы С++ && Литература об оптимизации С++

Tags: c++, оптимизация, синтаксис, rvalue

Во-первых, можно ли как-нибудь узнать полное имя типа в с++?
Я обычно использую `typeid(...)`, однако в один момент это сыграло против меня, т.к. в подобном коде сравнение typeid показало true:

```
struct mystr{
    int value;

    mystr(const int value) : value(value){}
    mystr operator+(mystr& other) { return mystr(value + other.value); }
};

int main(){
    mystr var(6);
    ( typeid(mystr(6)) == typeid(var) ); // true        
    var+var;                             //корректно
    mystr(6)+mystr(6);                   //Error, нет оператора "+" для данных операндов
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Как я понял, ошибка в том, что я передавал rvalue по ссылке, но почему так делать нельзя?

1. Мы вроде не выходим из области видимости и в момент выполнения функции объект существует,
2. а в стеке вроде тоже должна быть адресация?
3. Да, мы создаем на стеке функцию(не уверен), которая находится поверх этого объекта,
4. но объект мы никак не изменяем -> стек это не разрушит,
5. или это просто базовый запрет?

---

Во-вторых, только учусь, но хочу заниматься openGL/Vulcan/OpenCL/CUDA - т.е. тем, что строится на оптимизации, поэтому хотелось бы узнать название каких либо современных книг(желательно на русском) об оптимизации и о том, что кроется за абстракцией С++.

Comment: Ответ на какой вопрос вы хотите получить? Зачем вмещать всё в один?

Comment: 1) Не хотелось плодить кучу тем, новичок.
2) не уверен, но мой компилятор ее позволяет. Во всяком случае, это не отменяет вопроса о существовании корректной функции\объекта, в котором подобное допустимо.

Comment: 1), в принципе, несложно совсем, просто потребует немного кода (и сделать автоматически для всех возможных вариантов в текущем стандарте не получится).

Comment: извиняюсь по поводу typeid - просто не указал хэдэр `typeinfo` вот у меня и выбивалась ошибка

Comment: Извиняюсь за то, что в примере не указал этот хэдэр)

Comment: Раз уж новичок, значит читайте книги по C++, изучайте его. Постепенно придёт понимание многих вещей. Сейчас у Вас в голове откровенная каша, поэтому не нужно пытаться лезть в «оптимизацию».

Comment: А где именно у меня ошибки в данном примере?(я имею ввиду логические выводы о том, почему нельзя передавать rvalue в данном случае)
В голове у меня действительно некоторые пробелы и разупорядоченность, но, думаю, во многом тут дело в практике) Так же я считаю, что именно книги, которые рассказывают о том, что "кроется за абстракцией С++." и книги об оптимизации способны помочь понять в полной мере работу некоторых объектов. К тому же спрашивать немного заранее о них довольно разумно, ибо " а по оптимизации и того меньше — все куда-то подевались")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь сложить два rvalue, не имея для этого нужного метода. То есть ваш метод `operator+` здесь не подходит, так как не может работать с rvalue. Чтобы это исправить либо сделайте так:

```
mystr operator+(mystr&& other) { return mystr(value + other.value); }
```

либо (что, ИМХО, гораздо лучше), добавьте константность:

```
mystr operator+(const mystr& other) const { return mystr(value + other.value); }
```

P. S. Вы в вопросе указали: «но объект мы никак не изменяем» — вы-то, может, знаете, что объект не меняется, вот только об этом нужно сказать компилятору.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я уже ранее разобрался, просто это потребовало больше времени из-за моего неверного понимания typeid, недостатка опыта и более запутанного кода) 
Интересовал момент с rvalue, и, выходит, действительно, базовое ограничение, которое наложено из-за того, что мы можем порушить стек.